# Tkinter type error when configuring widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

When I login with the test credentials testuser:test, the main window refreshes only partially, and returns this error stack

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "N:\Subjects\Computer Science\Programming\gui manager (1).py", line 539, in get_info
    update_window(username)
  File "N:\Subjects\Computer Science\Programming\gui manager (1).py", line 560, in update_window
    main_window.config_widget("actions button",text="User actions",command=actions,fg="green")
  File "N:\Subjects\Computer Science\Programming\gui manager (1).py", line 429, in config_widget
    elif widget[0] == self.name: # If the widget has a name and it is the same as the passed 
parameter, configs widget
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1483, in cget
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'cget', '-' + key)
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

"relevant" (pertaining to callback) section: *hint: is in a class Root showed before, ergo I use self and run this as a class method

```
def config_widget(self,name,**kwargs):
    self.name = name
    self.kwargs = kwargs

    for widget_list in [self.button_list,self.entry_list,self.label_list,self.frame_dict.keys()]: # Iterates over list, of lists of types of widgets
        for widget in widget_list:  # Iterates over indiviual widget type list
            if widget == self.name:
                widget = self.frame_dict[self.name]
                for arg in self.kwargs:
                    self.value = kwargs[arg]
                    widget[arg] = self.value
            elif widget[0] == self.name: # If the widget has a name and it is the same as the passed parameter, configs widget
                for arg in self.kwargs:
                    self.value = kwargs[arg]
                    widget[1][arg] = self.value
```

full code:
https://1drv.ms/t/s!Ak6qBja0XlA7gV2zWKbCQ0J8Cdcl?e=PWPCUG

Comment: What do you expect `widget[0]` and `widget[1]` to mean?  If there's some possibility that `widget` might actually be something like a list of widgets, you'd need to explicitly check that before trying to index into the list, as that's not an operation supported by individual widgets.

Comment: @jasonharper yes thats it, i solved it by using try: except TypeError: pass. If you want to answer the question I'll mark it correct since you helped me solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to encase the config loop in a try: except TypeError: then pass if a TypeError is caught. The TypeError is raised when the program tries to index a widget which breaks the loop and prevents it from configuring the rest of the widgets.

Comment: I don't think this is the right answer, as it only ignores the problem rather than solving the root cause.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley I could just check for the type of the iteration variable in the for loop, however since it would achieve the same end, it is easier to use try and except, is it not?

Comment: The problem isn't with checking the index or catching an error, the problem is why the code is receiving an integer in the first place. It's likely a bug in the code that is calling this function where it's passing invalid data.